# Is there a tyre pressure gauge that is easy to use?

Tags: tires, gauges, pressure

I always lose air from a tyre when I try to use one of the type of pressure gauge that depress the pin in the valve as the gauge is attached, so I have to pump it up whether or not the pressure was already correct. It seems logical to me to have a fitting which attaches to the valve, with a button or other device that then presses the pin for a reading. Does such a gauge exist, or are there other types of gauge that do not present this problem to ham fisted users like me?

Comment: If you want to get really fancy there are aftermarket TPMS systems like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Schrader-SCH-BRK-4PC-Retrofit-Passenger-Wireless-Battery/dp/B008YQOZMG) that will give you a pressure reading in the car in real time.

Answer (score 3):

You can get valve caps that indicate tyre pressures on them in a Red/Amber/Green state.  They are available in a range of different pressures so you could replace your normal valve caps with them which would stop you even having to remove them to check the pressure.

[image: Example of pressure caps]

You can find more by searching for [Valve Cap Pressure Indicators](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=valve%20cap%20pressure%20indicators&safe=strict&noj=1&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=0CCIQsxhqFQoTCIuovtzB2MgCFQnZGgodcecAFg)